# R Add New Column to dataframe with Average by Week

Tags: r, dataframe

Okay, so I believe this is a simple problem, however I haven't seen a straighfoward solution that reflects my desired output.

Here is my dataframe:

```
day     | week_number | percent
Monday  |   1         | 15.3
Tuesday |   1         | 10.0
Friday  |   1         |  5.2
Monday  |   2         |  7.0
Thursday|   2         | 13.0
```

Below is my desired dataframe. I need to know: best solution to get desired outcome.

DESIRED OUTPUT:

```
day     | week_number | percent|week_avg
Monday  |   1         | 15.30  | 10.17
Tuesday |   1         | 10.00  | 10.17
Friday  |   1         |  5.20  | 10.17
Monday  |   2         |  7.00  | 10.00
Thursday|   2         | 13.00  | 10.00
```

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Maybe [these answers can help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7976001/adding-a-column-of-means-by-group-to-original-data)

Comment: `library(dplyr); df %>% group_by(week_number) %>% mutate(week_avg = mean(percent)`

Comment: @gregor thomas So with this i was able to create the "week_avg" variable, but how do I now add it to the dataframe ? When i do View(df) I dont see "week_avg" as new column

Comment: `df <- df %>% ...` to assign it back to the same name. Or `new_data <- df %>% ...` to create a new data frame.

Comment: By the way, this is what I used that worked :)

df1 <- df %>% group_by(x) %>% mutate(week_avg = mean(week))